# Collapsing pairs of duplicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a program in Prolog to collapse pairs of duplicates when they are next to each other.

Here's some examples,

[1,2,2,3,4] -> [1,2,3,4]

[1,2,2,2,3,4] -> [1,2,2,3,4]

What Im trying to do looks like this...

> ```
>  Look at the 3 elements in the front, 
>     if they are equal,
>     collapse them into 2, 
>     set head to 3rd element.
>
>  Look at 2 elements in front,
>     if they are equal,
>     collapse them into 1, 
>     set head to 2nd element. 
>
> Look at 2 elements in front,
>    if they are not equal,
>    do nothing,
>    set head to 2nd element.
> ```

I think this logic should work but I am very new to Prolog and dont know how to write this.

This is what I have

```
unecho([X],[X]).
unecho([X,Y,Z|XS],YS) :-
X=Y,
    Y=Z,
    unecho([Z|XS],YS).
unecho([X,Y|XS],YS):-
    X = Y,
    unecho([X|XS],YS).
unecho([X,Y|XS],[X|YS]):-
    X \= Y,
    unecho([Y|XS],YS).
```

When my input is unecho([1,2,2,2,3,4], X) my output is X = [1,2,3,4] when it should be [1,2,2,3,4].

Comment: *ollapse pairs of duplicates when they are next to each other*.... The result of `[1,2,3,4]` when you input `[1,2,2,2,3,4]` seems correct to me in that case. Can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @lurker Basically for every two, they collapse into one. [1,1]->[1] but [1,1,1]->[1,1] since the first two 1's collapse into 1 and then there is only a single 1 left on the tail.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I should only need to look at the first two elements of the list at a time then right? If the first two are equal collapse and set head to second element, otherwise don't do anything and set head to second element.

Comment: @PabloH You could also replace the last pair in each duplicate sequence, with the same effect. If I understand this question correctly, `unecho([1,2,2,2,2,3],X)` should unify `X` with `[1,2,2,2,3]` instead of `[1,2,2,3]`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I'm having trouble thinking of how I would do that but you're saying mine should work an it still isn't. Not sure if its an issue somwere else in the code

unecho([X],[X]).
unecho([X,Y|XS],YS):-
    X = Y,
    unecho([Y|XS],YS).
unecho([X,Y|XS],[X|YS]):-
 X \= Y,
 unecho([Y|XS],YS).
this is all it is now. sorry that didn't format correctly not quite familiar with stacks formatting options

Comment: @PabloH still unclear. Do you mean `[1,1,1,1] -> [1,1]` or `[1,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1]`? That's what "for every two they collapse into one" means to me.

Comment: @lurker [1,1,1,1] -> [1,1] because it has two pairs sequentially.

Comment: A couple of issues with your rules. You don't need the second clause at all. Your third clause has an error: your recursive call should be `unecho([Y|XS],YS).` not `unecho([X|XS],YS).`.

Comment: @lurker When you say the second clause you mean the one from the post or the one I commented above? Because in my current implementation I removed the second clause and changed "unecho([X|XS],YS)." to "unecho([Y|XS],YS)." and it still is not working.

Comment: You have four clauses for your `unecho/2` predicate. The second one is unnecessary.

Comment: @lurker Yes, I did away with that clause now I just have 3. One for the case where X is the only element in the list, one for where X and Y are equal and one for where X and Y are not equal. I changed the recursive call to be "unecho([Y|XS], YS)" and it is still not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the rule `unecho([X,Y,Z|XS],YS)`, because you can simply look at first two items `X` and `Y` of `[X,Y|Xs]`: in any case `X` becomes the head of the second list (and you'll never scan it again in the recursive calls); if `X` is equal to `Y`, then you just forget about `Y`, otherwise `Y` is prepended in the recursive call:

```
 unecho([X,Y|XS],[X|YS]):-
     X = Y,
     unecho(XS,YS).
 unecho([X,Y|XS],[X|YS]):-
     X \= Y,
     unecho([Y|XS],YS).
```

and you also need a predicate for the empty list:

```
 unecho([],[]).
 unecho([X],[X]).
```

otherwise `unecho([1,1],[1])` will fail.

Some tests:

```
?- unecho([1],X).
X = [1] .

?- unecho([1,1],X).
X = [1] .

?- unecho([1,1,1],X).
X = [1, 1] .

?- unecho([1,1,1,1],X).
X = [1, 1] .

?- unecho([1,1,2],X).
X = [1, 2] .

?- unecho([1,2,2],X).
X = [1, 2] .

?- unecho([1,2,2,2],X).
X = [1, 2, 2] .

?- unecho([1,2,2,2,2],X).
X = [1, 2, 2] .

?- unecho([1,2,2,2,3,3,4],X).
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] .

?- unecho([1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4],X).
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] .
```